# Multiple Tomcat instances configuration

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, multiple-instances

I have a Windows server that currently runs 2 different Tomcat instances as Windows services. Both have their own directories and don't share any files between them. The first Tomcat instance that was installed via the setup wizard set the CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE environment variables. The second one was installed in the same manner. It ignores the global settings and runs as a self-contained instance.

Here's the problem. I need to install a product which ships with its own Tomcat. I have finished installing the product but now I need to configure this Tomcat. When I run bin\tomcat7w.exe (the GUI control window) it picks up the settings from the first Tomcat that was installed on this machine. I suspect that it looks at the global CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE and ignores the fact that its in a different folder. Running bin\tomcat7w.exe in the second Tomcat's directory works as expected, ignoring the global environment variables.

I want tomcat7w.exe in Tomcat 3's directory to control Tomcat 3, not Tomcat 1. How can I configure Tomcat 3 to ignore the global environment variables set by Tomcat 1 and behave like Tomcat 2?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to fix the problem regarding the Tomcat monitor, tomcat7w.exe. However, I was able to get Tomcat3 to run. I deleted the global environment variables, CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE and registered Tomcat3 as a Windows service by using bin\service.bat. service.bat will complain about the missing variables but they can be set for the current session in CMD.